# Existence of ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{i}{2}]$ to a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, finite-fields, ring-homomorphism

> Does a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{i}{2}]$ to a finite field with characteristic $p\equiv 3 \bmod 4$ such that the unity is mapped onto the unity exist?

If $F$ is a finite field with characteristic $p$ and $\phi:R\to F$ exists, where $R=\mathbb{Z}[i/2]$, then from $i\in R$, we have $i^2=-1$ in $F$.  Therefore, $$\big(\phi(i)\big)^2=\phi(i^2)=\phi(-1)=-\phi(1)=-1.$$
What to do next?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there does exist such a homomorphism. Let $p$ be any prime congruent to $3$ mod $4$, and let $n$ be any even natural number. Then

- the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ has characteristic $p$
- there is a root $\alpha$ of the polynomial $x^2+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$
- since $p$ is odd, there exists a $\frac{1}{2}\in\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$

Then we can form the ring homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}[\frac{i}{2}]\to\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ defined by $f(1)=1$ and $f(\frac{i}{2})=\frac{\alpha}{2}$.

However, again with $p\equiv 3\bmod 4$, there is no homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}[\frac{i}{2}]\to\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ when $n$ is odd.

Comment: Nice answer....

Answer (score 6):

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $p$, where $p$ is a prime natural number.  Write $R$ for the ring $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{\text{i}}{2}\right]$.  Suppose $\varphi:R\to K$ is a ring homomorphism sending $1 \in R$ to $1 \in K$.  Assume that $\omega$ is the image of $u:=\dfrac{\text{i}}{2}$.  Then, we have $$4\omega^2=(2\omega)^2=\big(2\varphi(u)\big)^2=\big(\varphi(2u)\big)^2=\big(\varphi(\text{i})\big)^2=\varphi\left(\text{i}^2\right)=\varphi(-1)=-1\,.$$  (For this to make sense, $p \neq 2$.)

If $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, then clearly $\omega$ is in the prime field $\mathbb{F}_p \subseteq K$.  Elements of $R$ take the form $\dfrac{a+b\text{i}}{2^n}$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$.  Hence, $\varphi:R\to \mathbb{F}_p$ sends $\dfrac{a+b\text{i}}{2^n} \in R$ to $\dfrac{a+2b\omega}{2^n} \in \mathbb{F}_p$.  (Of course, there are two such $\varphi$'s.)

If $p \equiv 3\pmod{4}$, then $\omega$ lies within a subfield $E$ of $K$ isomorphic to $$\mathbb{F}_{p^2}\cong\mathbb{F}_{p}[x]/\left\langle x^2+1\right\rangle\cong \mathbb{F}_p[\text{i}]\,.$$  Consequently, for $\varphi$ to exist, $K$ must have such a subfield $E$ (and therefore, in the case that $K$ is finite, we must have $|K|=p^{2t}$, or $K\cong \mathbb{F}_{p^{2t}}$, for some $t \in \mathbb{N}$).  As elements of $R$ take the form $\dfrac{a+b\text{i}}{2^n}$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$, $\varphi:R\to E$ sends $\dfrac{a+b\text{i}}{2^n} \in R$ to $\dfrac{a+2b\omega}{2^n} \in E$.  (Again, there are two such $\varphi$'s for a given $E$ or $K$.)

To answer your question, if $p \equiv 3\pmod{4}$, such a homomorphism exists if and only if the finite field in question is of order $p^{2t}$ for some $t \in \mathbb{N}$.  If we omit the unitary homomorphism condition (i.e., $1\in R$ does not have to be mapped to $1\in K$), then we have one extra map for any prime $p$---the zero map.

**EDIT:** I just want to add a little note on some discussion I had with a user regarding the comments below.  To be clear, the term "ring homomorphisms" when rings involved may be nonunital will make no sense if we enforce the "unitary condition" (i.e., the multiplicative identity of one ring must be mapped to the multiplicative identity of another ring).   Hence, a homomorphism between two unital rings doesn't have to have this unitary property, but it will be called "unitary" if it satisfies this unitary condition.  It is not true that all homomorphisms between two unital rings must be unitary.

Let $f:R\to S$ be a ring homomorphism of rings $R$ and $S$.  Assume that the two rings are unital.  It doesn't matter (to him) wheter $f$ sends $1_R$ to $1_S$.  In his argument, let $g$ be the restriction of $f$ to its image (i.e., $g:R\to \text{im}(f)$ is identical to $f$).  There is no denial (from me) that $\text{im}(f)$ is a unital ring and $g$ would be a unitary ring homomorphism.  My point is, even that is so, it doesn't mean $f$ is also unitary.  For better clarification, I provided an example of a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$.  While this homomorphism isn't unitary, its restriction to the image is.

Comment: Are you saying that the zero map is not a ring homomorphism?  Very well, I guess that our definitions of ring homomorphisms differ.  The definition I use encapsulates the possibility that the rings involved are nonunital (hence, even if two given rings are unital, a homomorphism between them need not send the multiplicative identity of one ring to the multiplicative identity of another ring).  That is why I used the term "unitary homomorphisms."

Comment: For example, there is a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ sending $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ to $3\in\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I  was not discussing the zero ring anywhere.  It's you who suddenly brought this ring up out of nowhere.  Suppose $R$ and $S\neq 0$ are unital rings and $\phi:R\to S$ is the zero map.  Yes, $\text{im}(\phi)$ is isomorphic as a ring to the zero ring, and therefore, $\phi$ as a homomorphism from $R$ to the image ($0$) would be a unitary homomorphism, just like you claim.  HOWEVER, $\phi$ as a homomorphism from $R$ to $S$ is NOT a unitary homomorphism, because $\phi\left(1_R\right)=0_S\neq 1_S$.  Categorically speaking, $\phi:R\to S$ and $\phi:R\to 0$ are not even the same morphism.

Comment: Isn't that clear what the map $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ is if I give you the image of $1$?  The ring $\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by $1$, so you should have been able to work that out on yourself.  But since you asked, this map is given by $k\mapsto 3k$.

Comment: I was 100% wrong and I apologize for wasting your time. The question asked is only even meaningful under the correct interpretation of ring homomorphism as you have stated were the multiplicative identity is the codomain's and not the image's. Also this is not required either; in order for the question to again be meaningful. Well then.